# Angular app - why can my files / directives and the css file not be found?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, url-routing

I m building an angular app but my routing seems to be wrong no matter what i do. My nav bar directive can't be found just as the css file. Ive been looking at so many different posts etc but I still don't know what Im doing wrong.
Any help would be great!

project1/js/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>page</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../public/css/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/css/materialize.min.css">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.2/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"   src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-materialize/0.2.1/angular-materialize.min.js"></script>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="navbar.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">

    <navbar></navbar>
    <ui-view></ui-view>
</body>

</html>
```

project1/server/app.js

```
'use strict'

var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();
module.exports = app;
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../js')));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.listen(1337, function() {
    console.log('Server is listening on port 1337!');
});


var validFrontendRoutes = ['/'];
var indexPath = path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'public', 'index.html');
validFrontendRoutes.forEach(function(stateRoute) {
    app.get(stateRoute, function(req, res) {
        res.sendFile(indexPath);
    });
});
 app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    console.error(err.stack);
    res.status(500).send(err.message);
});
```

'use strict';

```
app.directive('navbar', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'js/navbar/navbar.html'
    }
});
```

project1/js/navbar/navbar.html

```
<div class="navbar navbar-static-top navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li>
            Hello
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Folder with pictures:

```
project1/public/css/style.css
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

paths in your html file should be relative to the static root you declare in the express.static() configuration

if your css file is placed under `projec1/public/css/style.css`
and you configure a static root using

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public')));
```

then your html should point to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
```

the same applies to js files

Comment: Thank you! And what about the navbar directive? I tried navbar/navbar.js or navbar.js but both is wrong and either it can't be found (when I do navbar.js) or Im getting a compile error when I do navbar/navbar.js

Comment: the file seems to be named navbar.html so the templateUrl reference should be: `templateUrl: 'navbar/navbar.html'`

Comment: okay thank you. If my index.html file wouldn't be in the same folder as my navbar-would the path then have to be js/navbar/navbar.js ?

Comment: the way you have configured routes in express, it doesn't matter where your index.html file is located on your server directory structure. You need to realize that with the express.static() and app.get() calls you are defining a virtual url structure where index will be found at the root ('/') and js and css files will be found under routes that result from mounting your local '../public' and '../css' folders onto '/' as well